# Язык C++. Замена delay на millis

Tags: c++, arduino

Вопрос от новичка. Как в этом коде delay заменить на millis? Чтобы не ставить на паузу выполнение остального кода программы.

Последовательность зажигания диода в этом алгоритме срабатывает разово, а не зациклена.

```
digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(ledblue, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(ledblue, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(ledblue, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(ledblue, LOW);
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под остальным кодом?

Comment: Под остальным кодом имеются в виду команды, выполняемые после этого кода, никак не связанные с управлением светодиода.

Comment: есть два основных способам - настроить таймер на срабатывание каждые 100 мс и в нем переключать светодиод в нужное состояние https://habr.com/ru/post/453276/ и второй способ -самому вызывать эту же функцию, а в  ней проверять текущее время и тоже "реагировать".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью машины состояний.

```
int timeouts[] = { 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2000, 0 };
int nstate = 0;
int start = 0;
bool high = true;

void setup()
{
    start = millis();
    digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    if (timeouts[nstate] != 0) {
        if (millis() - start >= timeouts[nstate]) {
            start = millis();
            if (high)
                digitalWrite(ledblue, LOW);
            else
                digitalWrite(ledblue, HIGH);
            high = !high;
            nstate++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас мигание зациклено, а в вопросе просят разово

Comment: Изменил, чтобы стало разово.